# Replace apostrophe ( ' ) in postgresql jsonb array object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-10

Please find the below jsonb object where i need to replace all apostrophe from instruction key.

```
    [{
        "instruction": "Don't need to book car for M'lore location",
        "reservationNo": "TT00098272"
    },
    {
        "instruction": "Please book a car for mumbai location",
        "reservationNo": "TT00098273"
    }
 ]
```

Expected Result : values are replace with apostrophe

```
[{
            "instruction": "Dont need to book car for Mlore location",
            "reservationNo": "TT00098272"
        },
        {
            "instruction": "Please book a car for mumbai location",
            "reservationNo": "TT00098273"
        }
     ]
```

Comment: Just check with `replace(jsoncolumn::text,'''','')::json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `regexp_replace()` after casting to `text`:

```
postgres=# create table j (field jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into j values ('[{
postgres'#         "instruction": "Don''t need to book car for M''lore location",
postgres'#         "reservationNo": "TT00098272"
postgres'#     },
postgres'#     {
postgres'#         "instruction": "Please book a car for mumbai location",
postgres'#         "reservationNo": "TT00098273"
postgres'#     }
postgres'#  ]'::jsonb);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select regexp_replace(field::text,'''','','g')::jsonb from j;
                                                                                    regexp_replace                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"instruction": "Dont need to book car for Mlore location", "reservationNo": "TT00098272"}, {"instruction": "Please book a car for mumbai location", "reservationNo": "TT00098273"}]
(1 row)
```